# git stash -> git commit --amend -> git stash pop の流れをスムーズに行いたい

Tags: git

コミットメッセージを修正するのに、

`git stash -> git commit --amend -> git stash pop`

するのが面倒です。

なにか良いアイデアはないでしょうか？

Comment: 作業ディレクトリがクリーンな状態であれば直接`git commit --amend`できるはずなので、想定しているのは作業途中で`stash`を使わなければ行けない状態が前提、ということでしょうか。

Comment: そうです！作業ディレクトリの状態を気にしたくないのです。

Comment: `git stash` しなくても `git commit --amend` のみでメッセージの修正ができると思うのですが、できない状況があるということでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu そうです。変更の一部をコミットして、コミットメッセージをミスったときとかです

Comment: @retake 具体的には `git commit` して何かしら `git add` してから、それは反映せずに HEAD~ のコミットメッセージだけ変更したい、というようなときでしょうか。なるほど、それならありえますね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

個人的には `commit --amend` 自体そこまで頻繁に使うものではない上、`git stash pop` の動作は `git stash` を実行したときスタックに詰むべき変更があったかどうかで変わってしまうのであまりオススメできませんが、一応一連の動作を Git エイリアスを使ってひとつのコマンドにまとめることができます。

```
[alias]
        stashamend = !git stash && git commit --amend && git stash pop
```